# Can i execute local internal server then try to show external content on my own powerBI custom visual?

Tags: node.js, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm having some problems trying to show external content or consume API from external services in my own powerBI custom visual, seems like PowerBI security policies doesn't want me to use external services but i want to confirm this.

What im trying to do is create a local internal server with nodeJS then that server has to show external content from a web like google or youtube (the content i want to show is bing map) once i do that then i generate a pbiviz package, import the file to power BI and show the page i specified.

Another cuestion i would like to know is **can power BI consume API from Google MAPS or Bing Maps and try to modify the map with my data?** Thanks you so much for the attention and answers.